# How to pass a variable from a windows form application to another non-form class, both in the same visual studio project?

Tags: c#

I have a c# class that has a method operating on a vsriwble file path. This file path has to be selected by the user by browsing(file system) in Windows form . The selected path in form is to be passed to the class so that it works. I tried instantiating form in the class. But this didn't work. This is my code in the c# class. I've another winform code to browse file path. I need to pass that path from there in this code.

Comment: I am not able to post the code here

Comment: can you please paste the relevant code of the class(in which the `path` is to be send) in here.

Comment: *I tried instantiating form in the class* Shouldn't that be in reverse means the `form.cs` should instantiate the class (where the path is to be used) and then call the particular class's method after it have the path?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code.

```
var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
{
   string filepath= FD.FileName;
   //Here you can pass "filepath" variable to your method.
}
```

Thanks,
Dileep.